# Why is the reactivity of a local collection messing up my UI?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-collection2, meteor-collections

I have this in the parent template:

```
{{#each oddsReactive in bet.oddsChecked}}
  {{>InputOdds arrayKey='oddsChecked' arrayIndex=@index}}
{{/each}}
```

The helper "bet" provides this data:

```
bet: () => ChecksCollection.findOne()
```

where:

```
ChecksCollection = new Mongo.Collection(null);
ChecksCollection.insert({
  oddsChecked: ['', ''],
  oddsAverages: ['', ''],
  oddsCompeting: ['', '']
});
```

I need "bet" to stay reactive because it's possible to add elements to the arrays from the parent template.

When I edit the text box from the child template (InputOdds), the focus is lost after each 'keyup'. Also at the first edit, it copies what I managed to write from the textbox of the first child template to the one of the second. Why? Why is the reactivity of the local collection messing up my UI?

```
Template.InputOdds.events({
  'keyup input.form-control': function (event, template) {
    template.currentOdds.set(event.target.value);

    var objectForSet = {};
    objectForSet[template.data.arrayKey + '.' + template.data.arrayIndex] = event.target.value;
    ChecksCollection.update({}, {$set: objectForSet})
```

As you can probably guess, if I comment out the last line, the UI is not messed up anymore. Please help me with this without recommending _.debounce or Meteor.setTimeout for the last lines, because they just postpone the messing up of the UI... I wish to have instant reactivity.

Probably unnecessary, but this is the html of the child template:

```
<template name="InputOdds">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="{{arrayKey}}{{arrayIndex}}">{{label}}</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="{{arrayKey}}{{arrayIndex}}" value="{{odds}}"
             placeholder="{{placeholder}}">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                      {{#if equals isValidOddsFormat 'yes'}}
                        <span style="color:green" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
                      {{/if}}
                      {{#if equals isValidOddsFormat 'no'}}
                        <span style="color:red" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                      {{/if}}
                    </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in Meteor's Blaze: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/6111

If anyone can think of a workaround, please clone that git, try to find it and let me know!